# options menu does not come up after back button press android

Tags: android, visibility, android-linearlayout, back-button, android-optionsmenu

I have an android application where I want to display a LinearLayout when user clicks on options button(I am setting the linear layout's visibility to visible in onCreateOptionsMenu) and make it invisilble when user clicks on back button.

This works fine when I press the option button and then the back button-the view comes up and then goes away respectively.

The problem is when I press the option button again, the linearlayout does not show even though the visibility is being set to visible.

However, log tells me that the methos onCreateOptionsMenu is entered. 
Why would this happen?

Comment: post more info (xml layout and some code) so we can help you more. The only thing may help you solve your problem is to try setting the linearLayout GOne instead of invisible, an maybe using the onPrepareOptionsMenu which is executed every time you see the menu instead of onCreateOptionsMenu which is only executed once per activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onCreateOptionsMenu` is called only once per activity. In your case you have to code in `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. This will be called every time the user presses menu key.

Comment: Why is the behaviour different for the android's built-in menu? The code for that menu works even if it is only written in onCreateOptionsMenu.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want do this? For android users relevant reaction for menu button is option menu.

What about question, try use `View.bringToFront()` - it will bring view in front of all views of the same parent.

Comment: but what is the view for the options menu?